# Two-conductor or four-conductor wire CAN bus

Tags: can

Can someone explain this to me? I got confused between these two CAN bus cables. A typical CAN bus only consists of two wires.

1. Where and when do we use four wires?
2. Are CAN-PWR & CAN-GND the same with supply power & GND?
3. If I just pass the CAN-GND, will it affect my CAN bus network in the vehicle?

[image: CAN bus cable]

Answer (score 6):

1. The minimum amount of signals used in CAN are 3: CAN High, CAN Low and signal ground. Fundamental data communication of any kind dictates that you absolutely must have a signal ground, thus the 2 conductor cable is hobbyist nonsense.

   There is a whole lot of broken, amateur CAN implementations on the market, where they share the supply ground with CAN signal ground. This is a no-go in the kind of applications where you usually find CAN, namely automotive or industrial. Those kind of applications tend to have very high currents and noise flowing through the supply ground. (In this context, "very high" is 1A or more.)

   Optionally, you can use a shield - not to be used instead of signal ground. Especially suitable for higher baudrates and also when longer cables are needed.

   If you use galvanically isolated CAN, you also need to provide power for the secondary side, to supply transceivers and isolator electronics. In this case the signal ground is the ground for the secondary side.
2. No, "CAN-PWR" refers to supply for a galvanically isolated CAN bus. "CAN-GND" refers to the mandatory signal ground.
3. A missing signal ground might cause all kinds of intermittent errors and jeopardize the reliability of the whole CAN bus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is the CAN-PWR is not quite necessary in the network? And, CAN-PWR cannot be used to power up other components for example LED,right?Because my friend said that it can be used for other purpose.

Comment: @Kayya1993 CAN power is necessary if, and only if, you are using isolated CAN. There's no reason why you couldn't use it to power up LEDs, for example to indicate that the secondary side of a device has power. As for how much current you can draw and what things you need to isolate, that depends on the application. Only the person who designed the application can tell you that. Needless to say, it shouldn't be used to power things that are also connected to the primary side.

Comment: "Fundamental data communication of any kind dictates that you absolutely must have a signal ground" - Sure? CANH+CANL are a differential pair; and what about current loops?

Comment: @JimmyB Differential signal doesn't matter, transceivers are only specified up to at best +/- 42VDC absolute maximum rating (for the common MPC2551 transceiver). With no ground, the potential difference between two different CAN nodes can be anything. The potential on vehicles in particular can dance around quite a bit, when something draws high current.

Comment: Still not convinced. Agreed, in practice you will/must have some point of common reference, but I think the wording using "fundamental", "dictates", and "absolutely must" is too strong. We're either in the theoretical field, where potential difference does not matter, or in a practical environment where 'infinite' differentials will not happen. That's also why I mentioned current loop data transmissions, thinking about opto couples wich provide for kV of isolation. Other than that, I'm all with you.

Comment: @JimmyB We're in the real world, where I have on several occasions encountered quack installations with no signal ground. This on vehicles and heavy machinery - safety/mission critical applications. The CAN bus on these vehicles would intermittently start spitting out bus errors or go down completely, resulting in a vehicle that suddenly stops doing what it is supposed to do. In each of these cases, adding a signal ground solved the problem. Obviously a galvanic isolation would also solve the problem, since then you have no choice but to provide a different ground.

Comment: Isn't *"Fundamental data communication of any kind dictates that you absolutely must have a signal ground"* and *"galvanically isolated CAN"* a contradiction?

Comment: CAN error frames should never occur, but on the other hand CAN devices are required to be somewhat tolerant of them. We have had vehicles stop after several hours of operation because a particular third-party CAN device was not tolerant of a CAN error frame on the order of one every 60 seconds     (probably because they implemented the standard in the wrong way).

Comment: @JimmyB You need signal ground, as much as you need *at least two wires* to have a current loop. Differential signalling for CAN is not balanced like ethernet.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah well if the faulty device can no longer communicate, that's usually bad enough. The reason why the whole bus can go down isn't the error frames though, but the missing ground. They are a side-effect of the problem.

Comment: I agree with @JimmyB. Adding a separate signal ground (assuming you can keep the power line noise out of it) simply moves the common mode noise problem behind the CAN transceiver. I don't really see how this helps matters. It makes much more sense to just deal with the noise on the differential pair using a common mode choke.

Comment: @Jon There is no "line" in automotive applications. The issue here isn't so much the noise from the supply (though surges can exist), as noise created by engine control, coils/valves, lighting, current spikes etc etc. The correct way to deal with that is to design the PCB with several grounds. But that doesn't help if your signal reference ground potential is all the noise on the whole machine combined, rather than a dedicated signal ground. That being said, creating noise filters on the CAN lines is a big topic of its own - there's some good app notes from ON Semi and others about it.